# How to put ComboBoxTableCell in a TableView?

Tags: combobox, javafx, tableview, tablecell

I'm trying to put a ComboBox in a table cell, but I can't. the code is the next:

```
private void cargaTablaDesglose() {
    TableColumn<Map, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>(Desglose1);
    TableColumn<Map, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>(Desglose2);
    TableColumn<Map, String> column3 = new TableColumn<>(Desglose3);

    column1.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Desglose1));
    column1.setMaxWidth(0);
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(null));
    column2.setPrefWidth(150);
    column3.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Desglose3));
    column3.setPrefWidth(250);

    if (CUOD.modifyData()) {
        column2.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Map, String> t) -> {
            actualizaObra(t.getRowValue(), t.getNewValue());
        });
            }

    tablaDesglose.getItems().clear();
    tablaDesglose.setEditable(true);
    tablaDesglose.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    tablaDesglose.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    tablaDesglose.getColumns().clear();
    tablaDesglose.getColumns().addAll(column1, column2, column3);

    Callback<TableColumn<Map, String>, TableCell<Map, String>> cellFactoryMap
            = CUCF.getFactoryMap();
    column1.setCellFactory(cellFactoryMap);
    column2.setCellFactory(cellFactoryMap);
    column3.setCellFactory(cellFactoryMap);
}
```

It says that can't found forTableColumn method of ComboBoxTableCell

Comment: `forTableColumn` method is static. You should call it `ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(null)` and pass valid arguments inside of it (like string converter and collection to create combobox upon).

Comment: I've created a ObservableList, an Array, a List and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try insert this simple example into your code and check that it worked: `column2.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(), FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3")));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part of the problem is that you're trying to set cell factory into cell value factory field of `TableColumn`. Try this instead:

```
ObservableList<String> cbValues = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3");

TableColumn<Map, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>(Desglose2);
column2.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(), cbValues));
```

Comment: You have to delete the fist DefaultStringConverter() before ComboBoxTableCell.for... and it works perfectly. Thank you!