# Set ComboBoxCell in TableView JavaFX

Tags: combobox, javafx, tableview

i followed the instructions from this question to set a ComboBoxCell in the TableView of my application. ([How to put ComboBoxTableCell in a TableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537358/how-to-put-comboboxtablecell-in-a-tableview))

The declaration of the Cell works fine, but the comboBox doesn't appear in the table. I think it's like this, because **only col1 and col2** are in my model. **col3 is not written in my table-entry** after the database connection.

I don't know how to takte the ComboBox in the TableView and need your help.

Here is my code:

controller:

```
package controller;

imports

public class main_controller implements Initializable {
    private ObservableList<model> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObservableList<String> cbValues = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3");

    @FXML
    private TableView<model> ComboTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<model, String> col1;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<model, String> col2;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<model, String> col3;

    public main_controller() {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        tableData.clear();
        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model, String>("rCol1"));
        col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model, String>("rCol2"));
        col3.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(), cbValues));

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("*** Loaded Oracle-Driver ***");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Driver-Loading failed.");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:lukas/1234@10.140.79.56:1521:OTTO");
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT NUMMER, DATEN1, DATEN2 FROM LUKAS order by NUMMER");
            String Daten1 = "empty";
            String Daten2 = "empty";
            // Zum einfügen kann man später auf diese Variable zurückgreifen.
            int columnIndex;
            System.out.println("*** Connected with Database ***");
            while (resultset.next()) {
                columnIndex = resultset.getInt("NUMMER");
                System.out.println("Tabellenindex der Zeile:\t" + columnIndex);
                Daten1 = resultset.getString("DATEN1");
                Daten2 = resultset.getString("DATEN2");
                System.out.println("Daten1:\t " + Daten1 + "\t\t\tDaten2: " + Daten2);
                **model entry = new model(Daten1, Daten2);
                tableData.add(entry);**
                }
            System.out.println("*** Database data saved to Observable List named 'data' ***");
            ComboTable.setItems(tableData);
            System.out.println("*** Table Items setted ***");
            statement.close();
        }   catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Login fehlgeschlagen.");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

model:

```
    package model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class model {

    private final SimpleStringProperty rCol1;
    private final SimpleStringProperty rCol2;

    public model(String sCol1, String sCol2) {
        this.rCol1 = new SimpleStringProperty(sCol1);
        this.rCol2 = new SimpleStringProperty(sCol2);
    }

    public String getRCol1() {
        return rCol1.get();
    }

    public void setRCol1(String set) {
        rCol1.set(set);
    }
    public String getRCol2() {
        return rCol2.get();
    }

    public void setRCol2(String set) {
        rCol2.set(set);
    }
}
```

The application looks like this right now:
[Picture](http://abload.de/img/applicationkto5u.png)

Hope you can help me!

Comment: The ComboBoxCell will be appeared when you double click that cell, namely you enter the edit mode. But first you need to see the whole picture, where you want to assign the selected value from combobox. What the cell will render initially etc.

Comment: Thank you!! Post it as answer and i answer the question. :)

Comment: Wait.. so your problem is resolved?

Comment: Yes :D Works^^ I setted the TableEditable to boolean true and after a double-click the box appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The declaration of the Cell works fine, but the comboBox doesn't
>   appear in the table.

The combobox of `ComboBoxTableCell` will be appeared when this cell is in edit mode. To do that you need to set the tableview to editable and then double click the over mentioned cell.

The quote from the ComboBoxTableCell javadoc:

> By default, the ComboBoxTableCell is rendered as a Label when not
>   being edited, and as a ComboBox when in editing mode. The ComboBox
>   will, by default, stretch to fill the entire table cell.