# Is it possible to display a changing arraylist in a Combo Box within a table in JavaFX?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, combobox, tableview

I have run out of options and not sure where to go from here to display the data that I need.

I have setup a table of type "Consultation" with multiple columns in correspondence to a Consultation class. One field of the consultation class (students) is an arrayList of strings, holding the student identification numbers. I want to display this array list per record within the table via a drop down fashion. For this, I was thinking a drop down ComboBox.

Is it possible at all for this to be achieved? I have attempted to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23537358/5579160)
solution to get Combo Boxes within a table cell, which works okay if the list is the same for all rows. My list changes for each record, so it doesnt really help my case

Note that the comboBox doesn't need to do anything either, just display the data

**Relevant Methods within the controller class**

```
public class ConsultationController {

private BackendInterface backendInterface;

@FXML TableView<Consultation> consultationTable;

private TableColumn<Consultation, Integer> consultIDColumn;
private TableColumn<Consultation, String> consultTitleColumn;
private TableColumn<Consultation, String> consultStartColumn;
private TableColumn<Consultation, String> consultEndColumn;
private TableColumn<Consultation, String> consultCategoryNameColumn;
private TableColumn<Consultation, String> consultPriorityNameColumn;
private TableColumn<Consultation, String> consultNoteColumn;

public void setupConsultationTable() {

    //setup table columns
    consultIDColumn = new TableColumn<>("Consultation ID");
    consultIDColumn.setMinWidth(60);
    consultIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("consultationID"));

    consultTitleColumn = new TableColumn<>("Title");
    consultTitleColumn.setMinWidth(60);
    consultTitleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("title"));

    consultStartColumn = new TableColumn<>("Start Time");
    consultStartColumn.setMinWidth(60);
    consultStartColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startTime"));

    consultEndColumn = new TableColumn<>("End Time");
    consultEndColumn.setMinWidth(60);
    consultEndColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("endTime"));

    consultCategoryNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Category Name");
    consultCategoryNameColumn.setMinWidth(60);
    consultCategoryNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("categoryName"));

    consultPriorityNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Priority Name");
    consultPriorityNameColumn.setMinWidth(60);
    consultPriorityNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priorityName"));

    consultNoteColumn = new TableColumn<>("Note");
    consultNoteColumn.setMinWidth(60);
    consultNoteColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("note"));

    consultationTable.getColumns().addAll(consultIDColumn, consultTitleColumn, consultStartColumn, consultEndColumn, consultCategoryNameColumn,
            consultPriorityNameColumn, consultNoteColumn);

}



public void loadAllConsultationTable(){
        consultationTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(backendInterface.returnConsultations()));
    }

}
```

**Consultation Class**

```
public class Consultation {
private int consultationID, categoryID, priorityID;
private String title, startTime, endTime, studentZID, categoryName, priorityName, note;
private ArrayList<String> students;

public int getConsultationID() {
    return consultationID;
}

public void setConsultationID(int consultationID) {
    this.consultationID = consultationID;
}

public String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public String getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}

public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

public Consultation(int consultationID, String title, String startTime, String endTime, ArrayList<String> students,
                    int categoryID, String categoryName, int priorityID, String priorityName, String note) {

    this.consultationID = consultationID;
    this.title = title;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.categoryID = categoryID;
    this.students = new ArrayList<>(students);
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    this.priorityID = priorityID;
    this.priorityName = priorityName;
    this.note = note;
}

public Consultation(int categoryID, int priorityID, String title, String startTime, String endTime,
                    ArrayList<String> students, String note) {
    this.categoryID = categoryID;
    this.priorityID = priorityID;
    this.title = title;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.students = new ArrayList<>(students);
    this.note = note;
}

public String getStudentZID() {
    return studentZID;
}

public void setStudentZID(String studentZID) {
    this.studentZID = studentZID;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {

    this.title = title;
}

public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}

public void setCategoryID(int categoryID) {
    this.categoryID = categoryID;
}

public void setPriorityID(int priorityID) {
    this.priorityID = priorityID;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public void setPriorityName(String priorityName) {
    this.priorityName = priorityName;
}

public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public String getPriorityName() {
    return priorityName;
}

public int getCategoryID() {
    return categoryID;

}

public int getPriorityID() {
    return priorityID;
}

public ArrayList<String> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public String zIDsToString() {
    String list = "";
    for (String student : students) {
        list += student + ",";
    }
    list = list.substring(0, list.length()-1);
    return list;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to change the list of items in the `updateItem` method of your table cell. See [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/) for example. If you already tried something like this please include the code for your table cell / cell factory and explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ObservableList<Consultation> consultationData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
tableDevices.setItems(consultationData);
int index = 0;
//here you have to add each instance of the class consultation  
columnComboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn< Consultation, Consultation >, TableCell< Consultation, Consultation >>() {

        @Override public TableCell< Consultation, Consultation> call(TableColumn< Consultation, Consultation > cbCol) {
            return new TableCell< Consultation, Consultation >() {


                final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(); 
                {                    
                    comboBox .setId(String.valueOf(index));

                }
                @Override public void updateItem(final Consultation consultation, boolean empty) {

                    super.updateItem(consultation, empty);

                    if (Consultation != null) {


                            if(index<=consultationData.size()){

                                System.out.println(consultation.getConsultationID());//just to see
                                comboBox.setItems((ObservableList) consultation.getStudents());                                   

                            }

                            index++;

                    }
                }

            };

        }

    });
```

Here's how i taught a solution, i don't know if it will work for sure, i did a similar think populating with some buttons the rows of the table(so i thing the solution for populate  each table cell with ComboBoxes it's not very far),  where each button must do a different thing based on the data of the record.
I hope it would be useful for you.